# Rails: puts statement on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In development puts "working" is shown on the console. In production this is not shown. But I need to show it on production as well.

For example:

```
def create
 puts "working on production and development"
end
```

I want to show `working on production and development` on production log as well. How can I do this?

Comment: use `Rails.logger` instead of `puts`. The message will be displayed on your production.log.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `logger.info`. puts only work in models etc. In controller you have to use  `logger.info "This is from info"`.